# Infinite loop with BufferedReader

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, tokenize

I'm trying to read certain inputs from the user using BufferedReader and StringTokenizer but the input does not terminate.

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  StringTokenizer st;
  st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
  N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
  M = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
  System.out.println(N+"\n"+M);
  for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
      System.out.println(st);
      int t1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
      int t2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
      ad.add(t2);
      path.put(t1, ad);
      System.out.println(t1+"and"+t2);

      //path.put(t2, t1);
      System.out.println(path);
  }
  st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());

  int s = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
  int t = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
```

It does come out of the loop though (Concluded this by using print statements).

And also the input format is:

```
3 3
1 3
1 2
2 3
1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this and it does break out of the loop. All I changed was removing lines that did not compile (ad.add(t2) and the next line) and putting "int" before the variable names...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st;
    st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
    int N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
    int M = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
    System.out.println(N + "\n" + M);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println(st);
        int t1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
        int t2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
        System.out.println(t1 + "and" + t2);

    }
    st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());

    int s = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
    int t = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
}
```

Output...

```
3 3 (I typed this)
3
3
1 3 (I typed this)
java.util.StringTokenizer@46f5331a
1and3
1 2 (I typed this)
java.util.StringTokenizer@bee145b
1and2
2 3 (I typed this)
java.util.StringTokenizer@3b7a687b
2and3
1 3 (I typed this)
```

Program then terminated

Comment: Ah, it terminated for me as well now, i.e. after I removed the same lines. Wonder what's wrong with that?

Comment: @AshishPatil What is "ad" and "path"?

Comment: private static HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> path = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

private static LinkedList<Integer> ad = new LinkedList<Integer>();

Comment: @AshishPatil I added the original lines back in and put the fields in your comment in and it still works...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out what the error was. It was actually another while loop inside the 'minPath' method, and nothing related to the above code haha.

Comment: @AshishPatil no probs - sometimes you need a second pair of eyes!!